# Relacionamento one-to-many Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

Estou desenvolvendo um crud de cadastro para um projeto. Ao fazer o cadastro o usuário(Employee) deve informar um `IdCity` que esta relacionado com a tabela cidades(Cities). Como é possível para que automaticamente eu consiga relacionar a coluna `CityName` ao `Employee` e mostrar isso na tela?

Classe Cidade:

```
namespace cruddef.Models

    {
        public class City
        {
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int CityId { get; set; }
            public string CityName { get; set; }

            public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Classe Employee:

```
namespace cruddef.Models
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int? CityId { get; set; }
        public City City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Contexto:

```
namespace cruddef.Models
{
    public class EmployeeContext : DbContext
    {
        public EmployeeContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        public DbSet<City> Cities { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<City>().HasData(new City
            {
                CityId = 1,
                CityName = "Carlos Barbosa"
            }, new City
            {
                CityId = 2,
                CityName = "Bento Gonçalves"
            }, new City
            { 
                CityId = 3,
                CityName = "Garibaldi"
            }, new City
            {
                CityId = 4,
                CityName = "Farroupilha"
            }, new City
            {
                CityId = 5,
                CityName = "Oslo"
            });

            modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasData(new Employee
            {
                EmployeeId = 1,
                FirstName = "Vinícius",
                LastName = "Bob",
                PhoneNumber = "999-888-7777",
                Email = "uncle.bob@gmail.com",
                CityId = 1

            }, new Employee
            {
                EmployeeId = 2,
                FirstName = "Jan",
                LastName = "Kirsten",
                PhoneNumber = "111-222-3333",
                Email = "jan.kirsten@gmail.com",
                CityId = 2
            });
        }
    }
}
```

O resultado exibido na tela é o seguinte:

```
0   
employeeId  1
firstName   "Vinícius"
lastName    "Bob"
phoneNumber "999-888-7777"
email   "uncle.bob@gmail.com"
cityId  1
city    null
1   
employeeId  2
firstName   "Jan"
lastName    "Kirsten"
phoneNumber "111-222-3333"
email   "jan.kirsten@gmail.com"
cityId  2
city    null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Na sua classe `Employee` você criou as propriedades de navegação e a propriedade que recebe o valor da chave estrangeira, porém em momento algum informa ao entity que ele deve usar esta propriedade como sendo a chave estrangeira para usar no relacionamento.

```
public class Employee
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int? CityId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CityId")]    //Indica ao entityframework que deve usar esta propriedade como chave estrangeira para usar no relacionamento.
        public City City { get; set; }
    }
```

Possa ser que seja necessario configurar esse relacionamento via fluenteAPI que você pode fazer simplesmente assim.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Employee>().HasOptional(e => e.City).WithMany(c => c.Employees);
//Desta forma você configur o relacionameto das classes via FluenteAPI, onde um Employee não é obrigatário ter City, e um city pode ter mais de um Employee.
```

E para que o carregamento dos dados relacionados seja incluidos nas pesquisas de forma automatica, você precisa criar suas propriedades navegacionais como `virtual`, assim você utiliza a opção `lazy load` para carregamento.

```
public class Employee
    {
        [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public int? CityId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("CityId")]    //Indica ao entityframework que deve usar esta propriedade como chave estrangeira para usar no relacionamento.
        public virtual City City { get; set; }
    }

public class City
        {
            [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
            public int CityId { get; set; }
            public string CityName { get; set; }

            public virtual List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
        }
```

Na hora em que você fizer uma busca de algum employee, ja irá trazer as informações da `City`a ele relacionado, e o mesmo acontecerá com a pesquisa no modo inverso, você pesquisando por `City` trará a lista com todos os `Employee` relacionados a esta `City` pesquisada.

```
using(var db = new SeuContext()){

    var city = db.Cities.First(c => c.id == algum_id); // Traz uma city ja com os employees relacionados

}
```

Tente essas alterações e veja se funciona para você.